# Splitting a string into every possible combination?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of every single possible splits of a string in python. For example, the string "abc" becomes `[("abc"), ("a", "bc"), ("ab", "c"), ("a", "b", "c")]`. This is the function I was using, but the time to run this function becomes unusable after around a string length of 15 (takes around 30 seconds). How can I fix this function (by using cache, etc...) so that it can run in an optimal time (hopefully under 1 sec)?

```py
def get_str_combinations(input_str):
    def _get_combinations(prefix, remaining):
        if not remaining:
            return [tuple(prefix)]
        
        combinations = []
        for i in range(1, len(remaining) + 1):
            combinations += _get_combinations(prefix + (remaining[:i],), remaining[i:])
        return combinations

    return _get_combinations((), input_str)
```

Comment: Do you need to implement it yourself? there are functions in `itertools` that do just that

Comment: This takes 0.04s on a string of length 15 for me. Are you sure you’ve described the right input size?

Comment: Actually it takes about 30 s on a string of length 25. Sorry

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah that was a typo, its ("abc",)

Comment: (Note that there are 2^(n-1) results, so there’s a certain unavoidable amount of slowness eventually.)

Comment: If there’s an underlying problem you’re trying to solve with this list of combinations, you should ask about solving that fast enough instead. [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @RobinLee I think every other combination is this `['acb', 'a', 'c', 'ab', 'cab', 'ac', 'bca', 'b', 'cba', 'bac', 'abc', 'bc']`

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907123/how-many-ways-can-a-natural-number-n-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-one-or-more-positi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it *slightly* faster (50% for me on a 25-character string) by

- building only one list and not creating intermediate ones
- removing one level of copying, slicing, and recursion

```
def get_str_combinations(input_str):
    combinations = []

    def _get_combinations(prefix, remaining):
        for i in range(1, len(remaining)):
            _get_combinations(prefix + (remaining[:i],), remaining[i:])

        combinations.append(prefix + (remaining,))

    _get_combinations((), input_str)
    return combinations
```

But there are 2^(n − 1) results for an input string of length n, each a distinct object with 1–16 subobjects. Doing this in Python is inherently slow. You’re probably not going to get it under a second, considering I can’t even get Python to do one multiplication per result in under a second:

```
$ time python3 -c '[i * i for i in range(2**24)]'
python3 -c '[i * i for i in range(2**24)]'  0.97s user 0.17s system 94% cpu 1.218 total
```

(Things like numpy can help if you change your representation, but this depends on what you’re using the list for. For example, just `range(2**24)` by itself is already a representation of the solution, since each element has a 1 bit corresponding to each split.)